# Get latest file directory wise in java

Tags: java

I have a path abc, in that path there are directories/sub-directories and files. Now, for eg if there is a directory 'A' & 'B' in which there are some files and there is subdirectory in which files are there. Same in 'B' directory. Now Output should be from 'A' directory we should get last modified file and same in 'B' directory.

I have done this much.

```
 public class GetLastModifiedFile {

    static TreeMap<String, String> map = null;
    static Entry<String, String> lastfile;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File currentDir = new File("D:\\myfiles"); // current directory
        map = new TreeMap<String, String>();
        displayDirectoryContents(currentDir);
        printFileList();

    }

    public static void printFileList() {
        for (Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            String value = entry.getValue();
            System.out.println(key + "      " + value);
        }
        lastfile = map.lastEntry();
        System.out.println("last file is" + " " + lastfile);
    }

    public static void displayDirectoryContents(File dir) throws IOException {

        String dateTime = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {

                displayDirectoryContents(file);

            } else {

                dateTime = sdf.format(new Date(file.lastModified()));
                map.put(dateTime, file.toString());
            }

        }

    }

}
```

output - i am only getting last modified file from all the directory and subdirectory. i want output like if i am in "A" directory than it should check first that it have subdirectory or files in it then should get last modified file from it before traversing to other directory.

Comment: did you try anything from your side to do it?

Comment: yes i have tried. i have managed to get all files from list of directories but i have to list file directory wise and get last modified file according to directory wise

Comment: Post whatever you have done so far. Input, current output and expected output. This is help everyone to understand the issue.

Comment: I have share whatever i have done please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find below a small snippet which does what you want to achieve.

For demonstration purpose it also generates some example directories and files.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Optional;
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MINUTES;

public class FindRecentFileRecursively {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // create some dummy directories/files
        Path root = Paths.get("/tmp/foobar");
        for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'C'; c++) {
            Path dir = root.resolve("dir_" + c);
            System.out.println("create sample directory " + dir.toString());
            Files.createDirectories(dir);
            long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
                File file = dir.resolve("file" + i).toFile();
                file.createNewFile();
                file.setLastModified(now + MINUTES.toMillis(i));
                printFileInfo(file);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("list the most recent file per directory");
        // find all directories below /tmp/foobar
        Files.find(root, Integer.MAX_VALUE, (path, attrs) -> attrs.isDirectory())
                // for each directory
                .forEach((dir) -> {
                    try {
                        // find all contained files
                        Optional<Path> recentFile = Files.find(dir, 1, 
                                  (path, attrs) -> attrs.isRegularFile())
                                // return the file with the recent last
                                // modification time
                                .max((p1, p2)
                                        -> Long.compare(
                                    p1.toFile().lastModified(),
                                    p2.toFile().lastModified()));
                        // if a file was found
                        if (recentFile.isPresent()) {
                            // print modification time and file name
                            printFileInfo(recentFile.get().toFile());
                        }
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
                    }
                });
    }

    private static void printFileInfo(File file) {
        System.out.printf("  mtime: %td.%<tm.%<tY  %<tH:%<tM:%<tS  file: %s%n",
                new Date(file.lastModified()),
                file.getAbsolutePath()
        );
    }
}
```

**output** like

```
create sample directory /tmp/foobar/dir_A
  mtime: 05.01.2016  15:35:15  file: /tmp/foobar/dir_A/file1
  mtime: 05.01.2016  15:36:15  file: /tmp/foobar/dir_A/file2
  mtime: 05.01.2016  15:37:15  file: /tmp/foobar/dir_A/file3
create sample directory /tmp/foobar/dir_B
  mtime: 05.01.2016  15:35:15  file: /tmp/foobar/dir_B/file1
  mtime: 05.01.2016  15:36:15  file: /tmp/foobar/dir_B/file2
  mtime: 05.01.2016  15:37:15  file: /tmp/foobar/dir_B/file3
create sample directory /tmp/foobar/dir_C
  mtime: 05.01.2016  15:35:15  file: /tmp/foobar/dir_C/file1
  mtime: 05.01.2016  15:36:15  file: /tmp/foobar/dir_C/file2
  mtime: 05.01.2016  15:37:15  file: /tmp/foobar/dir_C/file3

list the most recent file per directory
  mtime: 05.01.2016  15:37:15  file: /tmp/foobar/dir_A/file3
  mtime: 05.01.2016  15:37:15  file: /tmp/foobar/dir_B/file3
  mtime: 05.01.2016  15:37:15  file: /tmp/foobar/dir_C/file3
```

**update** To find the newest files per direct subdirectory of a given root the below snippet will do the work.

Assume a directory structure like

```
/tmp/foobar
/tmp/foobar/dir_A
/tmp/foobar/dir_A/sub_A
/tmp/foobar/dir_B
/tmp/foobar/dir_B/sub_B
/tmp/foobar/dir_C
/tmp/foobar/dir_C/sub_C
```

and you start with the `root` directory as `/tmp/foobar` the code will return the newest file in `/tmp/foobar/dir_A` and below, in `/tmp/foobar/dir_B` and below ...

```
System.out.println("list the most recent file per direct subdirectory");
// find all direct directories below /tmp/foobar
Files.find(root, 1, (path, attrs) -> attrs.isDirectory())
        // filter out the root itself
        .filter(p -> !p.equals(root))
        .forEach((dir) -> {
            try {
                // find all contained files in any subdirectory
                Optional<Path> recentFile = Files.find(dir, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 
                            (path, attrs) -> attrs.isRegularFile())
                        // return the file with the recent last
                        // modification time
                        .max((p1, p2)
                                -> Long.compare(p1.toFile().lastModified(),
                                   p2.toFile().lastModified()));
                // if a file was found
                if (recentFile.isPresent()) {
                    // print modification time and file name
                    printFileInfo(recentFile.get().toFile());
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
            }
        });
```

**output**

```
mtime: 08.01.2016  13:10:57  file: r:\temp\foobar\dir_A\sub_A\file1
mtime: 08.01.2016  13:11:39  file: r:\temp\foobar\dir_B\sub_B\file3
mtime: 08.01.2016  13:11:19  file: r:\temp\foobar\dir_C\file1
```

**edit** Following snippet also works with Java 6.

```
File root = new File("/tmp/foobar");
File[] topDirectories = root.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        return file.isDirectory();
    }
});
System.out.println("topDirectories = " + Arrays.toString(topDirectories));
for (File directory : topDirectories) {
    File recentFile = new File("");
    recentFile.setLastModified(0L);
    recentFile = getRecentFile(directory, recentFile);
    System.out.println("recentFile = " + recentFile);
}
```

.

```
// if you have a huge amount of files in deeply nested directories
// this might need some further tuning
static File getRecentFile(File dir, File baseFile) {
    File recentFile = baseFile;
    for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            recentFile = getRecentFile(file, recentFile);
        } else {
            if (file.lastModified() > recentFile.lastModified())  {
                recentFile = file;
            }
        }
    }
    return recentFile;
}
```

Comment: Hey, SubOptimal the answer you have posted does exactly what i want, but in your case, you are creating files and directory. I want if files and directory are already in path then how to find latest file. I am new to programming

Comment: @AnshSethi The `Path root = Paths.get("/tmp/foobar")` defines the top directory below the code will find all newest files in the below directory structure. The files and directories where only created for demonstration purpose to have a selfcontained runnable example. The code which does actually the search is below the line `System.out.println("list the most recent file per directory");`

Comment: That i got it sir, actually the problem is if there is any subdirectory inside the directory then it should return the latest file comparing from directory and subdirectory but in this case it is returning from both directory and subdirectory.

Comment: @AnshSethi Could you please add an example directory tree with some dummy filenames in your question. I don't get what you want. I understand your original question you did not want the newest file of the whole tree but for each directory level.

Comment: for example there is a path /tmp/test and in this path there are three folders 'a', 'b', 'c'. Now in 'a' folder there are 2 files a1.txt & a2.txt and inside 'a' folder there is subfolder 'abc' and in this subfolder there are 2 files t1.txt & t2.txt. Now when we are in /tmp/test/a it returns last file like a2.txt and when we are in  /tmp/test/a/abc it returns t2.txt. As, 'abc' is subfolder of 'a' so it should return only last file like from all these files a1.txt,a2.txt,t1.txt,t2.txt. Hope you understood

Comment: @AnshSethi You want the newest of all files below `/tmp/test` or the newest below each direct subdirectory of `/tmp/test`? e.g. the newest below `/tmp/test/a` in any subdirectory?

Comment: @AnshSethi Have a look in the added example.

Comment: Hey just want to ask why we have used Path class instead of File class. Is this thing can be achieved using File concept?

Comment: @AnshSethi Depends what you mean. In the given example `Path` cannot simply replaced by `File` as `Files.find(..)` expect a `Path`. If you mean traversing through the directory using `File.listFiles()` yes it's possible. But then you have to maintain the traversal through the directory tree yourself.

Comment: Actually in our production server we are using jdk 1.6 and path is supported in jdk 1.7,so have to code keep in mind the server configuration, if you can show a dummy example using File would be a great help

Comment: @AnshSethi Have a look in the added snippet. Was checked with the same structure like the first example.